# How to include header and footer of error document found in apache's custom error response package?

Tags: php, html, error-handling, apache

I have this line in my PHP script that includes a "*file not found*" 404 custom error provided by apache:

```
include('/var/www/error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var');
```

What is shown on my browser is just the body of the custom error page:

> Content-language: cs Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2
>   Body:----------cs-- Po�adovan� URL nebylo na tomto serveru nalezeno.
>   Zd� se, �e odkaz na ">odkazuj�c� str�nce je chybn� nebo zastaral�.
>   Informujte, pros�m, autora

The error page contains the following comments:

```
<!--#include virtual="include/top.html" -->
```

and

```
<!--#include virtual="include/bottom.html" -->
```

which are supposed to be the header and footer found in the include folder. But this is outside of my document root, `/var/www/html`.

How do I include the header and footer without moving the error folder into the document root?

Answer (score 0):

Configure include_path on php.ini and you can include them.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

or you can use php header function.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

also see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument you can have

```
ErrorDocument 404 /my_custom_404_handler.php
```

Comment: Do I `include_path = ".:/var/www/error"` or `include_path = ".:/var/www/error/include"`?

Comment: I think on /var/www/error/include has top and bottom you want to add. Since you include HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var  add /var/www/error and add /include just when you include top and bottom that way you can include any other from your custom folder too.

Comment: what do you see when you echo `get_include_path()` ?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your first comment. I see `:/var/www/error:/var/www/error/include` from echo.

Comment: are you keeping `<!--#include virtual="include/top.html" -->
` because this is SSI way to include replace those with php one

Comment: I didn't change a single thing in those files provided by apache in the error folder. The `HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var` file contains those lines. If I type a URL which points to nothing, the normal "file not found" error is shown, meaning the header and footer are properly included. But when I use php to include the same error file, the include virtual doesn't work.